# I set up metamask and added tokens. Now my Metamask shows Not Connected

Tags: metamask, connections

How do I get it connected? I can see my tokens and all of my information, but it still shows "not connected".

Answer (score 0):

"Not connected" indicates the page was not authorized to interact with metamask. Click on the indicator and a popup will appear where you can authorize your account.